# Kitchen Reno Drywall for backsplash

Tags: drywall, kitchens

I'm a doing a kitchen renovation, however I do not want to move the cabinets, I'm just replacing the doors. I do want to remove the existing ugly backsplash and add a new one. The current one is damaging the drywall as I remove it no matter how careful I am. It is like a 1/4" brick stuck to the wall.

How can I fix the damaged dry wall?

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

- Don't fix it. Install a backsplash that covers the damage.
- Or replace the damaged drywall, just like you would on any other wall.

Comment: Even better would be installing a cement based board (no mold, no water damage) as a backing and then putting your new backsplash on that.